# @-autocomplete for question author

Tags: feature-request, comments

Sometimes in comments under a question I want to make clear that I'm talking to the question author, not to some previous commenter. So I type `@` and their name's first letter, but their name doesn't show up among the auto-complete options to click on. Please include it.

Comment: From what I am aware this is only the case if the author is the only other person to have commented on the post. If that is the case why do you need `@` to autocomplete?

Comment: Oh, ok this happens also when the author hasn't posted any comments.

Comment: The entire exception rules for pinging are annoying. It can be really hard to figure out whether some old comments are a general remark or directed at a second party whose comments are gone.

Comment: You're always talking to the question author, including that is tautologous.

Comment: @RobertLongson Not true. Often I'm talking to a previous commenter who isn't the question author.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Actually it seems to *only* happen when the question author hasn't posted any comments. I just tried one where they had, and there it worked.

Comment: @KellyBundy, no your comment always notifies the author. It may also notify someone else as well.

Comment: @RobertLongson This isn't about getting notified. It's about clarity of communication.

Comment: re "Clarity of communication": Comments are not supposed to be a chat box at root. Their purpose is to bring remarks on the post, request clarifications or something else.
The fact we're usually abusing them to chat doesn't mean we should make it even greater for that.

Comment: @Tensibai If saying anything to someone other than the question author is an abuse, then why does the site offer @-autocompletion of them?

Comment: @Tensibai Also, this "chatting" can be about remarks on the post or clarification requests. For example when one commenter misunderstood or overlooked something and another commenter (who's not the OP) can clarify. Then that can lead to faster clarification or deletion. Have you never seen that, or do you disagree that that's a good thing?

Comment: Then this correction to someone else comment is already covered by @ name the commenter who's not the op, thus absolutely not what this post is about (enforcing the availability to @ the post author). In all ways: it's better to comment on fact/subject than addressing someone as it makes the name superfluous and avoid the need to wonder which comment from an author it relates too.

Comment: The distinction I think is in the usage of an @ when it ONLY is of interest to them and not to the author; then it is too chatty. Whatever you have to say, it should be for the benefit of the author of the post.

Comment: This would also help with discoverability of the ping feature: currently a new user joins the site, the first comments they receive won't have a `@` in them and then suddenly the user is supposed to know that pings exists. If they would directly see comment addressed to them with @-pings in them, the learning experience would be much more natural.